# Completar formulario con 2 condiciones de no repetir información en la base de datos con php

Tags: php, html, base-de-datos, mysqli

Tengo un formulario html con 6 campos, nombre, apellido, teléfono, correo, usuario y password, cuento con la base de datos y en el php quiero que me salte un alert con script cuando el $usuario se repite o $password se repite, la base de datos se llama industria y la tabla usuarios, existen 2 tipos de usuarios, 0 y 1,pero siempre se registran como 0;

```
<?php
Include('conexion.php');
Include('vars.php'); /*aquí guardo las variables*/
$queryvalidar1="SELECT usuario FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$usuario'";
$queryvalidar1=$mysqli->query($query validar) ;
mysqli_num_rows($query validar);
If ($queryvalidar1==0){
Echo "<script> alert ('el usuario \' $usuario\' ya se encuentra en uso') ;
History.go(-1);
</script>";
}
$passen=md5($pass);
$query="INSERT INTO usuarios (usuario, password, tipousuario) Values
('$nombre', '$apellido', '$telefono', '$correo', '$usuario', '$pass', 0);
$resultado=mysqli->query($query);

If($resultado>0){
Echo"<script>alert ('su registro fue exitoso');
Window.location.href='index.html';
</script>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Hola axlbasilio, bienvenido. ¿por qué motivo te preocupa si se repite o no la contraseña?.He observado que la consulta sql intenta insertar siete campos separados y que inserta $pass en lugar del password encriptado $passen. ¿podrías probar el código con ésto corregido e incluir la corrección en la pregunta? Un saludo!

Comment: solo me interesan 3 cosas, usuario, contraseña y el tipo de usuario (llamado "tipoUsuario" con el numero 1 y con el numero 2), estoy usando md5 en usuario y contraseña en la base de datos, tengo que el php del login tambien usa md5 en los dos y despues hace una consulta con el nombre de usuario md5 en ambos como identifico aparte que tipo de usuario es?
```
<?php
require ('cone.php');

$name=$_POST['name'];
$pass=$_POST['password'];
$hash=md5('$pass');
$hash2=md5('$name');
$CONSULTA="SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE usuario='$hash'";

if(){
}
?>
```

Comment: aparte, pues si  cada usuario sera enviado a su respectiva pagina, un admin.html y un user.html